# Sonos client certificate

Tags: https, certificate, sonos

I have a question concerning Sonos' **client** certificate. I didn't find any mention of it in the official documentation pages.

Do the speakers automatically send the client certificate on `getMediaUri` requests or does the server need to *require* it in the SSL negociation?

It would be neat if the speakers sent the client certificate **all the time**, because if the server needs to explicitly require the client certificate on the secure endpoint it means other APIs are impacted (`createItem` for example) whereas the only thing that really needs to be secured is the streaming url.

Answer (score 0):

The server does not need to require sending the cert on each request, but if you DO require it, it is something that can be sent each time.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Put differently: if I don't _require_ the client certificate server-side in the SSL negociation, will it still be presented by the speaker on a `getMediaUri` request?

Comment: No, it will not.  The server must require the client cert for us to send it

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation. Do you have an idea on how we could secure **only** the _getMediaUri_ call with client certificate? Or is it impossible to do?
If I require the client certificate on the secure endpoint, that means that it also impacts the following calls (if I read the documentation correctly): _getMediaMetadata_ for items within a _favorites_ collection, _createItem_, _deleteItem_ and _rateItem_, do you see a way of working around this?